# Cannot create binding for class DurableObject2 that is not exported by the script [code: 10061]

Tags: typescript, cloudflare, worker

I'm editing an old version of my CloudFlare worker to add a new Durable Object called `DurableObject2`

When I try to deploy it, this is the error. As you can see, the `dist/index.js` exports the class correctly.

```
% npx wrangler publish -c wrangler.staging.toml --outdir dist
 ⛅️ wrangler 3.0.0 (update available 3.15.0)
------------------------------------------------------
▲ [WARNING] `wrangler publish` is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version.

  Please use `wrangler deploy` instead, which accepts exactly the same arguments.


▲ [WARNING] Processing wrangler.staging.toml configuration:

    - "services" fields are experimental and may change or break at any time.


Your worker has access to the following bindings:
- Durable Objects:
  - DO: DurableObject
  - DO2: DurableObject2
- KV Namespaces:
  - DUMPS: xxxxx
  - API_KEYS: yyyyy
- Vars:
  - APP_URL: "xxxxxx"
Total Upload: 113.29 KiB / gzip: 25.41 KiB

✘ [ERROR] A request to the Cloudflare API (/accounts/wwwwww/workers/scripts/kkkkkkk) failed.

  Cannot create binding for class DurableObject2 that is not exported by the script [code: 10061]
  
  If you think this is a bug, please open an issue at:
  https://github.com/cloudflare/workers-sdk/issues/new/choose


% node
Welcome to Node.js v20.8.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> a = await import('./dist/index.js')
[Module: null prototype] {
  DurableObject: [class DurableObject],
  DurableObject2: [class DurableObject2],
  default: { fetch: [AsyncFunction: fetch] },
  notFound: [Function: notFound]
}
> a.DurableObject2
[class DurableObject2]
```

In my `src/index.ts` there're those 2 lines:

```
export { DurableObject } from './durableObject'
export { DurableObject2 } from './durableObject2'
```

The `wrangler.staging.toml` file is like:

```ini
name = "kkkkkkkkk"
main = "src/index.ts"
compatibility_date = "2023-10-30"

[[durable_objects.bindings]]
name = "DO"
class_name = "DurableObject"

[[durable_objects.bindings]]
name = "DO2"
class_name = "DurableObject2"

[[migrations]]
tag = "v1" # Should be unique for each entry
new_classes = ["DurableObject", "DurableObject2"]
```

It works if I remove all the references to `DurableObject2`, keeping just `DurableObject`. Where do I make the mistake?

Answer (score 2):

The issue probably was in the migrations part. I said "probably" because, in the end, I deleted the worker and reinstalled it. Anyway, I also added a 3dh DurableObject and the error returns. Changing the migration part, the deployment goes well.
It was just a nasty error message.

The solution was

```ini
[[migrations]]
tag = "v1" # Should be unique for each entry
new_classes = ["DurableObject"]

[[migrations]]
tag = "v2" # Should be unique for each entry
new_classes = ["DurableObject2"]
```

Comment: Yeah I believe this is the correct answer, I didn't delete the worker, and just added the migrations, and everything starting working as expected.